# Why is Visual studio 2022 intellisense not working on unreal engine 4.27?

Tags: unreal-4

I am new to unreal engine. Whenever I add a new class on unreal engine and open it in visual studio 2022 the intellisense doesn't seem to work for instance if I write #include "" it does not show me all the components. I have added the game development with C++ in visual studio installer?

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same issue. I found a temporary fix for it though; try using <> instead of "".

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the docs. VS 2019 is the best suited for Unreal version 4.27.

https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/ProductionPipelines/DevelopmentSetup/VisualStudioSetup/

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/107265)